# Finding the total number of possibilities of inside angles of convex pentagons

Tags: geometry

I don't have much formal math beyond intro calculus.  So please forgive me if I use the wrong words.

The use of computers to find the [fifteenth tiling pentagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling#Mann.2FMcLoud.2FVon_Derau_.282015.29_Type_15) type has been interesting to me.  As a novice exercise to myself, I wanted to see if I could determine the total number of combinations of inside angles of all pentagons.

Starting from my understanding that the total of the inside angles of a pentagon is 540 degrees ((number of sides -2) * 180), and that each inside angle is less than 180 degrees, and keeping angle values as whole numbers, how could I determine the permutations (or is it combinations) to express all the possibilities that I could test further to see if they tile on themselves.

Again, I understand that I might be able to make this number of total possible tiling pentagons smaller with additional knowledge of geometry and if there is something that would help I'd like to read that also.

Comment: Do you really want to know this number? It is a standard combinatorial problem to determine it. Your life span would not suffice to go through all cases. More important: Why do you think that the involved angles are integer multiples of ${\pi\over180}$ and, more important, that it will be an easy matter to deal with the potential side lengths corresponding to the envisaged angles?

Comment: I would like to know how to get to this number.  It is a problem I had trouble with getting.  It's not that I would go through these cases myself but I'd like to know if it is a number small enough to run through a computer.  My guess would be yes.  I would think the angles would be between 1 and 180 degrees. Maybe I did not say what I meant properly.  I guess I had not thought further enough to consider different potential side lengths if I had the angle measurements.